# Change dom with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want change dom with jquery.

It is source:

```
<td class="name"><a href="position_details.php?x=-109&amp;y=95">21</a> </td>
<td class="name"><a href="position_details.php?x=-109&amp;y=96">22</a> </td>
<td class="name"><a href="position_details.php?x=-109&amp;y=97">23</a> </td>
```

I want change that to it:

```
<td class="name"><a href="position_details.php?x=-109&amp;y=95">21</a> :.: <a href='http://d3.traaviaan.ir/build.php?gid=16&t=99&action=showSlot&sort=distance&direction=asc&x=-109&y=$3$4'>Add to farm list</a></td>
<td class="name"><a href="position_details.php?x=-109&amp;y=96">22</a> :.: <a href='http://d3.traaviaan.ir/build.php?gid=16&t=99&action=showSlot&sort=distance&direction=asc&x=-109&y=96'>Add to farm list</a></td>
<td class="name"><a href="position_details.php?x=-109&amp;y=97">23</a> :.: <a href='http://d3.traaviaan.ir/build.php?gid=16&t=99&action=showSlot&sort=distance&direction=asc&x=-109&y=97'>Add to farm list</a></td>
```

Tings can change is:

QueryStrin's value.

And text of anchor.

I tried this code but it doe`

```
$(".name").each(function(index){
   str = $(this).html();
   str = str.replace(/[<]a href="position_details[.]php[?]x=([-]?)([0-9]+)&amp;y=([-]?)([0-9]+)">(.+)<\/a>/, 
   "<a href='position_details.php?x=$1$2&y=$3$4'>$5</a> :.: <a href='http://d3.traaviaan.ir/build.php?gid=16&t=99&action=showSlot&sort=distance&direction=asc&x=$1$2&y=$3$4'>Add to farm list</a>");
  $(this).html(str)
```

});

`

Comment: is it some botScript?

Comment: give us `$(this).html()` exact result...

Comment: @vp_arth No it just for learning

Comment: yes @vp_arth is right. It is working already see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z7m11yua/4/)

Comment: I think no `&amp;` entities in original urls.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.name').each(function() {

    var that = $(this);
    var hrefPart = that.find('a').attr('href').split('?');

    that.append(".::.<a href='http://d3.traaviaan.ir/build.php?gid=16&t=99&action=showSlot&sort=distance&direction=asc&" + hrefPart[1] + "'>Add to farm list</a>");
});
```

The position part form the first link is split off, that's the easiest way.